# Issue with logout on Azure AD B2C and ASP.NET Core

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am playing with ASP.NET Core and Azure AD B2C, when using the code sample from GitHub ([active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore-b2c](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore-b2c)) the logoff part does not work.
in the Account Controller

```
        [HttpGet]
    public async Task LogOff()
    {
        if (HttpContext.User != null && HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            string scheme = (HttpContext.User.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/authnclassreference"))?.Value;
            await HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            await HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync(scheme.ToLower(), new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" });
        }
    }
```

the scheme has a null value returned. I can't find a way to logoff properly. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is looking for an "acr" claim and apparently not finding one.
Open Azure portal and navigate to your Azure AD B2C, then check the "Token, Session and SSO config" section in **each** of your sign-in/sign-up policies.
Under Token Compatibility Settings, you should have the following switch as shown:

[image]

If the switch has tfp selected (which is the default position), the auth token will contain no "acr" claim, therefore it won't be added into the collection of claims of the ClaimsPrincipal object after login, and is subsequently unavailable to your code in the LogOff method.
Hope this helps.

Comment: This answer works, but I think a better solution would be to modify the claim search to find the "tfp" policy id.

Answer (score 0):

Alex is correct.  If you don't modify your code, you should change the representation to "acr".

*However*, "acr" is only provided for backward-compatibility and Microsoft recommends that "tfp" should be used instead.  [Azure Active Directory B2C: Token, session and single sign-on configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-token-session-sso)

I recommend that you modify the example code as shown below.  I also [submitted a pull request](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore-b2c/pull/8) to the original author with similar code.

```
        if (HttpContext.User != null && HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // try to find the tfp policy id claim (default)
            var scheme = (HttpContext.User.FindFirst("tfp"))?.Value;

            // fall back to legacy acr policy id claim
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(scheme))
                scheme = (HttpContext.User.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/authnclassreference"))?.Value;

            await HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            await HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync(scheme.ToLower(), new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" });
        }
```

Comment: Correct. It's preferable to convert to the "tfp" claim.
The only thing I tend to dislike about short-named claims is the lack of a standardized URI, but that's more of a personal preference thing.